# Using regular expression to replace special characters outside of html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to find and replace some special html entities, i.e. '&' converts to `&amp;` and '>' converts to `&gt;`. This is for an email builder tool, and some older clients need characters replacing with html entities.

The user passes through a string, and I use javascript to loop through an array of objects. This finds a character and replaces it with the correct html entity.

You can see the regex code I'm using here:

https://regex101.com/r/WZh5tA/2

```
    escapeCharacter: function(string){
      var replaceChar = [
        {reg : '&', replace: '&amp;'},
        {reg : '"', replace: '&quot;'},
        {reg : '£', replace: '&pound;'},
        {reg : '€', replace: '&euro;'},
        {reg : 'é', replace: '&eacute;'},
        {reg : '–', replace: '&ndash;'},
        {reg : '®', replace: '&reg;'},
        {reg : '™', replace: '&trade;'},
        {reg : '‘', replace: '&lsquo;'},
        {reg : '’', replace: '&rsquo;'},
        {reg : '“', replace: '&ldquo;'},
        {reg : '”', replace: '&rdquo;'},
        {reg : '#', replace: '&#35;'},
        {reg : '©', replace: '&copy;'},
        {reg : '@', replace: '&commat;'},
        {reg : '$', replace: '&dollar;'},
        {reg : '\\(', replace: '&#40;'},
        {reg : '\\)', replace: '&#41;'},
        {reg : '<', replace: '&lt;'},
        {reg : '>', replace: '&gt;'},
        {reg : '…', replace: '&hellip;'},
        {reg : '-', replace: '&#45;'},
        {reg : "'", replace: '&#39;'},
        {reg : '\\*', replace: '&#42;'},
        {reg : ',', replace: '&sbquo;'}
    ];
    var s = string;
    replaceChar.forEach(function(obj){
      var regEx = new RegExp(obj.reg+"(?!([^<]+)?>)", "g");
      s = s.replace(regEx, obj.replace);
    });

    return s
  }
```

The problem occurs when the user passes a string with html tags (which they should be allowed to do). For example, the string could be:

```
'This is an example of some <b>bold</b> text'
```

My find and replace tool works it's magic, but I think I'm missing something because I get this output:

```
'This is an example of some <b>bold</b&gt; text'
```

Comment: If your content contains HTML tags, then it would seem to imply that the entire content is in fact HTML, in which case you should _not_ be using regex to handle your replacements.

Comment: what is expected output

Comment: As a partial solution you can replace `</` temporarily with `<#` and recover it again after proccessing.

Comment: Use `s = s.replace(new RegExp("(<[^<>]*>)|" + obj.reg.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "g"), function ($0,$1) { return $1 ? $0 : obj.replace } );`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's not a HTML document, it's a handlebars partial that has a string passed to it. In this instance, it's a paragraph partial, but the user might need to pass through <b> or <a> tags if needed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know what kind of regular expression wizard you are, but that seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replace(
      new RegExp("(<[^<>]*>)|" + obj.reg.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "g"), 
          function ($0, $1) { return $1 ? $0 : obj.replace } 
);
```

Notes:

- You need to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) the `obj.reg` before  using in a regex expression, hence `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` is required
- The `(<[^<>]*>)|` alternative matches and *captures into Group 1* `<...>` substrings before the required matches and in the callback method passed as the replacement argument, there is a check if the first group matched. If it did, the whole match is returned back as is, else, the replacement occurs.